# init method of parent state is not calling when navigate from child to parent state using angular ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

**What I tried so far**

**app.js**

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']);

```
    itaasContentApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');

        $stateProvider.state('parent', {
            url:'/parent',
            templateUrl :'partials/parent.html',
            controller:'parentCtrl'
        })
          .state('parent.child',{
            url:'/child',
            templateUrl :'partials/child.html',
            controller  :'childCtrl'
        });
```

parentCtrl

```
    app.controller('parentCtrl', function($scope,$state) {

    var init=function()
    {
    //it will initialize the controller 
    }

init();
    //I am calling child state
    $state.go("parent.child");

    });
```

childCtrl

```
        app.controller('childCtrl', function($scope,$state) {

            init=function()
            {
            //it will initialize the controller <html data-ng-init='init()'>

            }
    //calling init

    init();

$scope.goBack=function()//I will call this method from  view
{
$state.go('^');
}

            });
```

**Problem**

- While navigating from child state to parent state init() of parent is
  not calling can you please help with this

Comment: It looks like anytime you call the parent state, you will automatically then switch to the child state regardless of where you're coming from.  Is there a reason you have it setup like this?

Comment: why it should be called? Parent state was initialized already, now you inside it and there is no reason to reinit it.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov  init() will get the data from server i need to call again when the view shown

Comment: @RobertMcCraw updated question please check now

Comment: May be it should be two different states then?

Comment: @RobertMcCraw No , When you change something in child state the data  will save in server which i need show in parent 
I need to follow this approach only i mean parent -- > child

Comment: Maybe we could get some more information?  You're changing something on the $scope in the child state and this change is not making it to the parent state?  I kindof agree with Petr, you're not really making a full state change when you move from child to parent, you're just moving up the tree, so the init method has already happened and probably won't happen again.  Why not make them different states?